# Jqgrid pager (top or bottom) too many custom buttons then it overflows pictures and texts, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, pager

When too many icons are added to navigator pager (top or bottom)  a picture and text overflow is show.

But, behavior I want is: "buttons will be wrapped on the next row of pager (top or bottom) automatically if too many icons are added and the grid have not so large width".

Top pager example here:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid(
                {
                    url : 'value_url',
                    datatype : 'json',
                    mtype : 'GET',
                    colNames : [
                            'Estudiante Id',
                            'Cedula',
                            'Nombres y Apellidos',
                            'Sexo',
                            'Número Expediente'
                            ],
                    prmNames : {
                        id : 'estudianteId'
                    },
                    colModel : [...],
                    postData : {},
                    rowNum : 15,
                    rowList : [ 10, 15, 20, 30 ],
                    height : '100%',
                    autowidth : true,
                    shrinkToFit : true,
                    rownumbers : true,
                    pager : '#pager',
                    toppager : true,
                    sortname : 'cedula',
                    viewrecords : true,
                    sortorder : "asc",
                    caption : "Listado Estudiantes",
                    emptyrecords : "No se encontraron estudiantes",
                    loadonce : false,
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        $("#pager_right").attr('width', 150);
                    },
                    jsonReader : {
                        root : "rows",
                        page : "page",
                        total : "total",
                        records : "records",
                        repeatitems : false,
                        cell : "cell",
                        id : "estudianteId"
                    },
            });


    $("#grid").jqGrid(
        'navGrid',
        '#pager',
        {
            edit : false,
            add : false,
            del : false,
            search : false
        },
        {},
        {},
        {},
        { // search
            sopt : [ 'cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt',
                    'bw', 'ew' ],
            closeOnEscape : true,
            multipleSearch : true,
            closeAfterSearch : true
        });

$("#grid").jqGrid(
        'navGrid',
        '#grid_toppager',
        {
            edit : false,
            add : false,
            del : false,
            search : false
        },
        {},
        {},
        {},
        { // search
            sopt : [ 'cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt',
                    'bw', 'ew' ],
            closeOnEscape : true,
            multipleSearch : true,
            closeAfterSearch : true
        });


function activar_top_pager()
{
    $("#grid_toppager_left").html('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="float: right; table-layout: auto;" class="ui-pg-table navtable"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');

    $("#grid_toppager_center").html('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="float: right; table-layout: auto;" class="ui-pg-table navtable"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');

    $("#grid_toppager_right").html('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="float: right; table-layout: auto;" class="ui-pg-table navtable"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');

    $("#grid_toppager_center").width('1px'); 

  $("#grid_toppager_right").width('1px');   
}

activar_top_pager();

$("#grid").jqGrid('bindKeys');
$("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Op. ", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Operaciones ",
    id: 'btnope',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton1", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton1",
    id: 'b1',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 });  $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton2", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton2",
    id: 'b2',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton3", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton3",
    id: 'b3',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton4", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton4",
    id: 'b4',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton5", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton5",
    id: 'b5',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton6", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton6",
    id: 'b6',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton7", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton7",
    id: 'b7',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton8", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton8",
    id: 'b8',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton9", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton9",
    id: 'b9',   
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 }); $("#grid").jqGrid ('navButtonAdd','#grid_toppager',{
    caption: "Boton10", buttonicon: "ui-icon-locked", title: "Boton10",
    id: 'b10',  
     onClickButton: function() {
    }
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3frm92d0/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You demo uses old version 4.6 of jqGrid. The problem is known in the version. You can actual 4.15.5 version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which is compatible to jqGrid 4.6, but contains a lot of new features (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), READMEs and [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). It supports wrapping of navigator buttons (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Redesign-of-the-structure-of-Navigator-Bar-of-the-pagers)).

Additionally you should don't use `activar_top_pager` function of your demo. Instead of hiding central pager you should comment `rowNum : 15`, `rowList : [ 10, 15, 20, 30 ]` options and to add `pgbuttons: false` and `pginput: false` options. To hide right pager you need comment `viewrecords : true` option:

```
//rowNum : 15,
//rowList : [ 10, 15, 20, 30 ],
//viewrecords : true,
pgbuttons: false,
pginput: false
```

You will see the results on the modified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/41qv5xsu/12/.

By the way, if you do want to display some part of pager you can specify the width of the part of the page using `pagerLeftWidth`, `pagerCenterWidth` or  `pagerRightWidth` parameters.

Comment: Thanks it solves partially my problem (buttons now wrap), but created a new one, for me toppager and bottompager are differents in fact their buttons are  created dinamically depending on users privileges and data source, but bottom pager need viewrecords and text and buttons, but top doesnt need it and then if I use viewrecords : false, pgbuttons: false, pginput: false it make the trick but for both pagers and I want to hide only in top but leave it in bottom.

Comment: I solve temporary with a little ugly hack on loadComplete I used: ("#grid_toppager_center").hide(); and $("#grid_toppager_right").hide();   but I have pages with multiples jqgrids nested (like 20 or more) and I want to know: are there better options than this? I'm using 4.15.6-pre version of free jqGrid.

Comment: @Proyecto: If you need to hide parts of top-pager only then you have to do that explicitly with the code like `var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"); $(p.toppager + "_right," + p.toppager + "_center").hide();`. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/41qv5xsu/38/ where I make some other small code optimizations.